# Unique id property could not be found from Material-UI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Error: Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property. I am seeing when I call the table.
Here is my code. I know that the _turbineId field is unique in the dataset.

Here is how I have the table defined.

```
const columns = [
  {
    field: "siteName",
    headerName: "Wind Farm",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "turbineName",
    headerName: "Turbine Name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "controller",
    headerName: "Controller Type",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "swVersion",
    headerName: "Software Version",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "location",
    headerName: "Country",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "_turbineId",
    headerName: "Turbine Name",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
  },
];
```

Here is how I define the rows

```
const rows = windFarmData.map((data) => [
  {
    siteName: data.SiteName,
    turbineName: data.TurbineName,
    controller: data.Controller,
    swVersion: data.SoftwareVersion,
    location: data.Country,
    _turbineId: data.TechnicalId,
  },
]);
```

Here is the datagrid

```
export default function DataTable() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={(r) => r._turbineId}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wonder if I have missed something or done something wrong.

Comment: make sure _turbineId is unique

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I replaced this:

```
    const rows = windFarmData.map((data) => [
  {
    siteName: data.SiteName,
    turbineName: data.TurbineName,
    controller: data.Controller,
    swVersion: data.SoftwareVersion,
    location: data.Country,
    _turbineId: data.TechnicalId,
  },
]);
```

with this:

```
const rows = sortWindFarmData;
```